# How to install rasa nlu 0.10.4 on gunicorn as socket?

Tags: python-3.x, artificial-intelligence, rasa-nlu

I want to install `rasa_nlu 0.10.4` on gunicorn server on socket.
I have created separate daemon process to run it with command

```
exec Rasaenv/bin/gunicorn -w 1 --threads 3 -k gevent -b unix:/RASA_DIR/gunicorn.sock rasa_nlu.wsgi
```

but it could not start.
It was working for old version of RASA. It is giving an error

> 'Model Error: rasa_nlu.wsgi model does not found' even though I have
>   installed rasa_nlu.

Please Help.